# Programmatically get list of all Built-in types

Tags: c#, .net, types, built-in

I got all the built-in types from the [Built-in types table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table).
Is there a way to programmatically get this list?
I do not know how to use reflection, so I have no idea how to even start. I have got no code yet.

Comment: Why not just hard code it in? It's not something that will change during runtime...

Comment: Just curious: Why do you need that? Whether types are built-in or part of the framework is typically irrelevant for the application.

Comment: @PMF As I stated before, I do not know how to use reflection. I was just curious whether it is possible. The statements: 
            _listElementType = GetListType(_list);
            string name = _listElementType.Name; _isSystemType = name.GetType().Namespace == "System"; // This will return System (the namespace containing the type) if it is a System type (a in-built type) will tell me if it is a system type.

Comment: @user2102327: That's a very vague test. There are types in the system namespace that are not normally considered built-in (i.e. all the exception types, the `Console` or the `Environment` class). And in fact, nothing prevents you from creating new types in that namespace yourself (although thats not a good idea).

Comment: @PMF Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: @PMF May be this is a better approach: bool _isSystemType = typeof(T).IsPrimitive; (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_IsPrimitive)

Comment: That will give you the _primitive_ types, which is not necessarily the same (ie. System.String is builtin, but not primitive). The solution will clearly depend on what you intend to do with that information.

Comment: `typeof(Type).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsPrimitive)` Will give you list of all primitive types. `String` and `Object` are not primitive, but considered as simple types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It's not a good idea to get those types using reflection.
>   **Just for learning purpose** you use the following snippets.

Get framework primitive types full names:

```
var frameworkTypesFullName = typeof(Type).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.IsPrimitive).Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();
```

Get C# alias names for primitive types:

```
var cs = new CSharpCodeProvider(); //dispose later or put in using statement
var csharpTypesAlias = typeof(Type).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.IsPrimitive).Select(x =>
        cs.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(x))).ToList();
```

There are also `System.String` and `System.Object` which are not primitive but usually names as *Simple Types* with `string` and `object` alias in C#.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would wish to know though why you said: "It's not a good idea to get those types using reflection".

Comment: You're welcome. That's because you can easily define an array containing those types with less penalty compairing to using reflection to search between all types in an assembly.